# MySQL reverse record list

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in mysql to read from table from its ending?
What I have now is:

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.username, u.level, g.name, h.address
 FROM users u 
 LEFT JOIN groups g ON u.group_id = g.id
 LEFT JOIN home h ON u.home_id = h.id
 WHERE level < 100 
 ORDER BY u.id DESC
```

This works fine. But when there are millions of users this gets laggy. Using MySQL's explain shows that it is using where and filesort to select rows. This make whole thing quite slow. Removing the ORDER BY query runs like five times faster. 
I tried adding index on level and id but it didn't helped.
Of course, I could just rearrange the script to select entries from the bottom of the table and reverse them. Sadly, at this point I don't know the number of rows in the table. 
Any suggestions appreciated.

**Update:** The EXPLAIN results

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref        | rows    | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL       | 1677300 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | g     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | u.group_id |      1  |                             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | h     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | u.home_id  |      1  |                             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

**Update**
I found that in this case a second query with count(*) does work much faster.

Comment: I assume you have an index on `u.id` as it is a primary key? Because that would be the first place to look if the `ORDER BY` is slowing you down.

Comment: We'd really need to see the EXPLAIN and DDLs to help further

Comment: Yup, u.id is the primary key.

Comment: Is `u.level` indexed? You use this column in WHERE clause.

Comment: And what is the result?

Comment: It takes about 1.2 seconds for both queries.

Comment: My answer was total rubbish, sorry about that - deleted - please ignore